# Chromeデベロッパー・ツールのjavascriptエラー(main.js)について

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Google Chrome(Mac)でWebサイトの開発をしております。
テキストボックスやプルダウンなどに入力・変更したりすると、Chromeデベロッパー・ツールのコンソールに以下のように表示されております。
作成しているサイトではmain.jsといったようなファイルは使用しておらず、当該エラーがなぜでるか・解消できるか教えていただけますでしょうか？

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
main.js:64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Chrome のデベロッパーツールの上部に "Network" というタブがありますので
それをクリックして情報を確認してみてください

左上のマル印が赤くなっている状態で作成しているサイトをリロードすると
サイトを表示する時に読み込まれているファイルが一覧で出力されます

その中に問題の 「main.js」 は見つかりませんか？

見つかったらそのファイルが設置されている場所が記載されていますので
そのファイルに問題があります

見つからない場合
可能性として考えられるのは Chrome の拡張機能です

Chrome にインストールされている拡張機能に問題がありそうなものはありませんか？

Comment: ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。確認した所、最近追加した「速訳！英辞郎®英和辞書 1.1.10」という拡張機能によるもので、無効化したら解決いたしました、ありがとうございました。